# ANTLR 3: passing value to Lexer (C target)

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Is there a mechanism to pass a value to a lexer?  (I'm working with C target in ANTLR 3)

Some other search results had suggested putting a function and var into the member area:

```
@members
{
    bool read_flag;
    void set_flag(bool b) {read_flag = b;}
}
```

however, that does not seem to work. The set_flag() is a global for the lexer, but not able to be called from outside

I want to be able to do something like this in the calling code:

```
//some input stream
pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM input =
    antlr3NewAsciiStringInPlaceStream((pANTLR3_UINT8)buf, len, NULL);

pmyLexer lxr = myLexerNew(input);
lxr->set_flag(true);
```

Comment: I'm not sure about C target but this should be doable with C++ target.

Comment: PS: C target does not know anything about objects. The lexer is a "fixed" struct which contains pointers onto various "member" functions. Each "member" function accepts pointer onto lexer as a 1st, parameter. So if you extended this struct you would call it as `lxr->set_flag(lxr, true)`. Also there are not member variables, but there might be three volatile void* pointers in the struct called "user1, .., user3" as far as I rememeber.

Comment: An alternative might be to create a global function outside of the lexer struct that I could call  
for example in lexer.h:  
    'bool f;
    set_flag(bool)'  
I don't really see any action that allows me to just add something to the header though.  Using @header puts the contents into the header and .c file

Answer (score 1):

You can use the user pointer for that, which has been added exactly for this purpose:

```
lexer->pLexer->rec->state->userp = &context;
```

In my lexer I use this to store a reference to my RecognitionContext structure, which I then access via macros in my grammar:

```
#define PAYLOAD ((RecognitionContext*)RECOGNIZER->state->userp)->payload
#define SERVER_VERSION ((RecognitionContext*)RECOGNIZER->state->userp)->version
```

The structure is defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    long version;
    void *payload;
    ...
} RecognitionContext;
```